# Mailchimp API - Method to get list of campaigns per user

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am using the Mailchimp API to collect info about list members (per email), and campaigns. However, I am not seeing a method to collect a list of campaigns that were sent to a specific email/list member.

Am I missing something?

Comment: hey, did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

First get list of all campains. And in loop of campains, and check if user exists in list. mailchimp provide api ti check if user contains in list.

Comment: Slowest information query in the history of computing, one might say.